# Python Popen not recognizing command line switches

Tags: python, popen

I have a Python script with the following two lines of code (as well as other lines) running on a Linux server:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['last', '-F'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = proc.communicate()
```

When I run `last -F` from the command line on the server (Linux), everything is great. The `-F` switch puts dates in a more standardized format. (It stands for "full," I believe--so the year isn't omitted, even if it's the current year.)

However, when I run my script, Popen is definitely not invoking the `-F` switch. The date information I am getting is definitely not "full." Does anyone see what is going wrong here? It might be worth noting that I have tried both `shell=True` and `shell=False`, but the `-F` option doesn't seem to take effect either way.

--EDIT--

The kind of output I am getting:

```
mlecoz   pts/4        10.31.202.4      Sat May 19 13:46   still logged in
```

The kind of output I want (important for parsing reasons):

```
mlecoz   pts/4        10.31.202.4      Sat May 19 13:46:34 2018   still logged in
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: The Linux **last** command do not have -F flag but have -f in lower case.

Comment: @dhke - Yes I'll update the question to include that.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE If you look at the man page, there is both an -f and -F, and I need the uppercase one.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I need to do is remove the last parameter from the call:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['last', '-F'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

so that it is:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['last', '-F'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```